# Typescript claims it is a CustomType | Undefined, but it should be only CustomType

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The problem I have is different, but the core of the problem is listed bellow. [Typescript Playground link for the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjgdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBuTAX00wGMAbfOOWBRAMpIAblTYQAsgHs2AawzYcUMAFcARhzFRuIXGyi0IweEgAUASjIAFRFMJUEAHhOIAPitwATCADMaETwA%20LCVQqEQjFURcDAJiMgAiABUICgSmRlCWFnYpXAooYXxNT3xgCABRAA8HYBpaF1QoUxV%20MkbXKA9vP1wAy20eJGBeVqQoBz5xlECFHCofUwBCMcRzOaVgAAtbAHcoPv2KxFtEUwByADkpLv4oHylu8-NMqGyoVjY8gsJ8GiadHpmusZgpFDgOEZbkh2ndOt1fP5POCoF98sBoYIRGJoGhDlMsYhROJpHILK8cKsAbs-hjVkIiTiAHSGYz8clQAD0nKgpNkAXutkI5Gx4lYoSKJTKlRqFHqLha-HM4qU3KgAHUqNsoNtJpB8OIoFIfKipN4JhjdlJELJeNwoBAqpA2OVkaE1QtlqtzCFVTzQts9gcIEcTtaLtdMc8UWqcqE0XApJCmRwpLRFUgXsxWL8aBZWEA)

Here is the working code.

```
type User = {
   name: string;
}

let user: User | undefined
user = await UserService.getUserById(1)

if(!user) {
   throw new Error('No user found');
}

await passUserToAnotherFunction(user) // <-- user is defined here and of type User
```

If I want to do user validation logic in different function and throw an error there, the user in passUserToAnotherFunction is of type User | undefined. Here is an example:

```
type User = {
   name: string;
}

let user: User | undefined
user = await UserService.getUserById(1)

validateExistingUser(user)

await passUserToAnotherFunction(user) // <-- Here user is of type User | undefined and this line is red

const validateExistingUser(user: User | undefined) {
  if(!user) {
    throw new Error('No user found');
  }
}
```

Why is it behaving like this when this function executes the same lines of code and how to avoid it?

Comment: It's usually a good a idea to share your code at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play so everybody can easily play with it.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjgdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBuTAX00wGMAbfOOWBRAMpIAblTYQAsgHs2AawzYcUMAFcARhzFRuIXGyi0IweEgAUASjIAFRFMJUEAHhOIAPitwATCADMaETwA+LCVQqEQjFURcDAJiMgAiABUICgSmRlCWFnYpXAooYXxNT3xgCABRAA8HYBpaF1QoUxV+MkbXKA9vP1wAy20eJGBeVqQoBz5xlECFHCofUwBCMcRzOaVgAAtbAHcoPv2KxFtEUwByADkpLv4oHylu8-NMqGyoVjY8gsJ8GiadHpmusZgpFDgOEZbkh2ndOt1fP5POCoF98sBoYIRGJoGhDlMsYhROJpHILK8cKsAbs-hjVkIiTiAHSGYz8clQAD0nKgpNkAXutkI5Gx4lYoSKJTKlRqFHqLha-HM4qU3KgAHUqNsoNtJpB8OIoFIfKipN4JhjdlJELJeNwoBAqpA2OVkaE1QtlqtzCFVTzQts9gcIEcTtaLtdMc8UWqcqE0XApJCmRwpLRFUgXsxWL8aBZWEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, you only need to make it an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions):

```
function validateExistingUser(user: User | undefined): asserts user is User {
  if(!user) {
    throw new Error('No user found');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tokland, seems like it didn't solve an issue, especially now I am getting an error on validateExistingUser call saying:
Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.
'validateExistingUser ' needs an explicit type annotation.

Comment: @AmelAmcëMuminovic Can you share a snippet in play to know exactly what you have?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjgdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBuTAX00wGMAbfOOWBRAMpIAblTYQAsgHs2AawzYcUMAFcARhzFRuIXGyi0IweEgAUASjIAFRFMJUEAHhOIAPitwATCADMaETwA+LCVQqEQjFURcDAJiMgAiABUICgSmRlCWFnYpXAooYXxNT3xgCABRAA8HYBpaF1QoUxV+MkbXKA9vP1wAy20eJGBeVqQoBz5xlECFHCofUwBCMcRzOaVgAAtbAHcoPv2KxFtEUwByADkpLv4oHylu8-NMqGyoVjY8gsJ8GiadHpmusZgpFDgOEZbkh2ndOt1fP5POCoF98sBoYIRGJoGhDlMsYhROJpHILK8cKsAbs-hjVkIiTiAHSGYz8clQAD0nKgpNkAXutkI5Gx4lYoSKJTKlRqFHqLha-HM4qU3KgAHUqNsoNtJpB8OIoFIfKipN4JhjdlJELJeNwoBAqpA2OVkaE1QtlqtzCFVTzQts9gcIEcTtaLtdMc8UWqcqE0XApJCmRwpLRFUgXsxWL8aBZWEA

Comment: I have added the link. Check it out

Comment: Check https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34523. Use `function` instead of an arrow function.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjgdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBuTAX00wGMAbfOOWBRAMpIAblTYQAsgHs2AawzYcUMAFcARhzFRuIXGyi0IweEgAUASjIAFRFMJUEAHhOIAPitwATCADMaETwA+LCVQqEQjFURcDAJiMgAiABUICgSmRlCWFnYpXAooYXxNT3xgCABRAA8HYBpaF1QoHw82OrzTFX4yRtcoD28-XADLbR4kYF4upCgHPhmQ2Z9TAEJpxHMFUOAAC1sAdyhhw4rEW0RTAHIAOSl+-mapAcvzTKhsqFY2PILCfBomjo9FALKhAgpFDgOEZ7kgeg8+gNfP5PJCoN98sBYYIRGJoGhjvMcYhROJpHILG8cOtAft-lj1kISXiAHSGYz8SlQAD03Kg5NkAWatkI5Fx4lYoSKJTKlRqFHqLk6-HMkqUvKgAHUqLsoLs5pB8OIoFIfOipN5Zlj9lJELJeNwoBAqpA2gE0RqqMs1irFjgNds9lJDoTTucrrdsS8PXycqEMXApNCWRwpLRlUhXsxWH8aBZWEA

Comment: In the link above you can see I have just tried with function instead of arrow one, but it seems like it is not solving an issue. However, the workaround would be to return a user from validateExistingUser if the user exist, but it is workaround

Comment: Check the answer, please, use a named function.

Comment: Awesome, that worked, this will get a plus and accepted as a solution. Good work tokland